# Error while initializing the Office JS Excel Add-In

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

The Excel Add-In Office.initialize function never returns and raises the below error after a while.

```
    Office.initialize = () =>
    {
        const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
        platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
```

[image: The initialize error]

```
excel-web-16.00.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_appName' of null
at Object.b [as callback] (excel-web-16.00.js:24)
at w (excel-web-16.00.js:24)
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue for an app I am running on localhost for development purposes. My production version of the app seems unaffected.... Any luck on solving this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons that I know of that you might be seeing this error.

**Manifest Points To The Wrong Resource**

If your manifest has an incorrect urls, your add-in will not load.

For example:

Your server is hosting on http://localhost:4200, but your Excel Addin manifest points to https://localhost:4200

One possible indication that this is your problem, is that the button icons are not loading on your ribbon.

**Excel Addin Requires SSL**

If you Excel ribbon icons load, but the app does not load, you might be able to fix the issue by running your app with ssl.

For Angular users testing in development you can achieve this by running:

ng serve --ssl

Note that angular automatically generates an ssl certificate when using the ssl flag above, but it only lasts for 30 days. To create a new one you will need to delete the cert generated in node_modules and run the command again if it expires.

This solved the problem for me when running an Angular locally in development.

Comment: Confirmation that ssl is required for development: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1854